# why SELECT CAST('1cat' AS SIGNED) = '1cat'; is true?

Tags: mysql

I don't get it, why cast('1cat' as signed) that is 1 and the string '1cat' are the same for mysql, I tried several times also I running this on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_cast4 but it is a mistery for me

I try run this

```
SELECT CAST('1cat' AS SIGNED) = '1cata';
```

and also is true, it is like after the number ignore all

Comment: Mysql tries it's best to parse the data you give it. In this case it took the number and discarded the strings. Note that `1cat1` will result in just `1`.

Comment: Implicit type conversion is what is taking place here. The left hand side is a number(as you have used the CAST method to change the type of the string to a SIGNED), the right hand side is a string, so type conversion is being carried out by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!!

```
SELECT strcmp(CAST("1cat" AS signed),'1cat')=0;
```

this works!! yay